# Select customer with two or more license types, selecting only the first type

Tags: sql, t-sql

<strike>I have a customer list with duplicates based on their license type.  If a customer has a license for foo and a license for bar (a subset of foo), the end user only wants to see the customer record for bar.</strike>

The records look like this:

```
id | fName | lName | address | city | st | zip | Region | Email | Gender | licenseID | Description | Age
```

if I have these two records, I want to only return the one with licenseID 5:

```
324580 | Bob | Jones | 123 Any Street | Anytown | 12345 | 1 | bob@anyemail.com | M | 1 | 'Foo' | 30
324580 | Bob | Jones | 123 Any Street | Anytown | 12345 | 1 | bob@anyemail.com | M | 5 | 'Foo' | 30
```

My query currently looks like this:

```
select c.firstName as [First Name], c.lastName as [Last Name], ca.street1 as [Street 1], ca.street2 as [Street 2], ca.city as [City], ca.stateAndTerritoriesID as [State], ca.zipCode5 as [Zip], le.LawEnforcementRegionID as [Region], c.emailAddress as [Email], c.genderTypeID as [Gender], cl.licenseTypeId as [License ID], l.description as [Description], (DATEDIFF(yy, c.birthDate, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(c.birthDate) > MONTH(GETDATE())) OR (MONTH(c.birthDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(c.birthdate) > DAY(GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Age]
    from [srvr].[dbo].[Customers] c
  join [srvr].[dbo].[CustomerAddresses] ca on c.id = ca.customerID
  join [srvr].[dbo].[CustomerLicenses] cl on c.id = cl.customerId
  join [srvr].[dbo].[FIPSCountyCodes] ccc on c.CountyID = ccc.ID
  join [srvr].[dbo].[LicenseTypePriceAndFeeDistributions] f on cl.licenseTypeId = f.id
  join [srvr].[dbo].[LicenseTypes] l on cl.licenseTypeId = l.id
  join [srvr].[dbo].[LawEnforcementRegionCounty] le on ccc.CountyCode = le.CountyID
  where cl.licenseTypeId in (001, 002, 004, 005, 019, 070, 071, 072, 073, 074, 120, 085, 086, 091, 092, 093, 164, 166, 167, 168, 169, 189, 198, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406  )
  and ccc.StateCode = 47
  and cl.startDate > '02/01/2019'
  and ca.addressType = 'M'
  group by c.firstname, c.lastname, ca.street1, ca.street2, ca.city, ca.stateAndTerritoriesID, ca.zipCode5, c.emailAddress, c.genderTypeID, cl.licenseTypeId, le.LawEnforcementRegionID, c.birthDate, cl.startDate, l.description, ca.countyID
  order by c.firstName, c.Lastname, cl.licenseTypeId, datepart(yyyy,cl.startDate)
```

I am not getting any errors, but I need to cut out the extra 800-ish duplicate records of folks with both a type 1 and type 5 license, and I have no idea how to go about doing that.  It would be easy enough to write a C# app that would do the comparisons and remove the dupes, but that feels like shooting a fly with a shotgun.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT TO ADD:

The customer wasn't clear on his expectations.  It turns out he wanted to to have 1 single record for each customer, with the license types purchased by that customer.  And he doesn't care about the description of the license.  I ended up going with this:

```
select c.id as [id], c.firstName as [First Name], c.lastName as [Last Name], ca.street1 as [Street 1], ca.street2 as [Street 2], ca.city as [City], 
         ca.stateAndTerritoriesID as [State], ca.zipCode5 as [Zip], le.LawEnforcementRegionID as [Region], c.emailAddress as [Email], c.genderTypeID as [Gender]
        ,stuff((select distinct ',' + cast(zz.licenseTypeId as varchar(10)) from [srvr].[dbo].[CustomerLicenses]  zz 
                where zz.customerId = c.id and zz.isvoided = 0  and zz.startDate > '02/01/2019' 
                and zz.licenseTypeId in (001, 002, 004, 005, 019, 070, 071, 072, 073, 074, 120, 085, 086, 091, 092, 093, 164, 166, 167, 168, 169, 189, 198, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406  )
                for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as [License Types]
                ,(DATEDIFF(yy, c.birthDate, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(c.birthDate) > MONTH(GETDATE())) OR (MONTH(c.birthDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(c.birthdate) > DAY(GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Age]
   from [srvr].[dbo].[Customers] c
  join [srvr].[dbo].[CustomerAddresses] ca on c.id = ca.customerID
  join [srvr].[dbo].[CustomerLicenses] cl on c.id = cl.customerId
  join [srvr].[dbo].[FIPSCountyCodes] ccc on c.CountyID = ccc.ID
  join [srvr].[dbo].[LicenseTypePriceAndFeeDistributions] f on cl.licenseTypeId = f.id
  join [srvr].[dbo].[LicenseTypes] l on cl.licenseTypeId = l.id
  join [srvr].[dbo].[LawEnforcementRegionCounty] le on ccc.CountyCode = le.CountyID
  where cl.licenseTypeId in (001, 002, 004, 005, 019, 070, 071, 072, 073, 074, 120, 085, 086, 091, 092, 093, 164, 166, 167, 168, 169, 189, 198, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406  )
  and ccc.StateCode = 47
  and cl.startDate > '02/01/2019'
  and ca.addressType = 'M'
  group by c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname, ca.street1, ca.street2, ca.city, ca.stateAndTerritoriesID, ca.zipCode5, c.emailAddress, c.genderTypeID, cl.licenseTypeId, le.LawEnforcementRegionID, c.birthDate, cl.startDate, l.description, ca.countyID
  order by  c.id
```

If I have the two records shown above, I now return this:

```
324580 | Bob | Jones | 123 Any Street | Anytown | 12345 | 1 | bob@anyemail.com | M | 1,5 | 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption in this potential solution. 
If the only conditions are `licenseID` = 1 or 5 and you always want 5 if duplicates exist, you could try using `max` on `licenseID`. This would return the maximum value if there are duplicates, which in this case would be 5. You could then remove `licenseID` from the `GROUP BY` clause. I don't know your data set either, so if that is not correct please reply back and I'll try again!

Comment: see the "where cl.licenseTypeId in..." line; there are 29 licenseIDs I'm querying against.

Comment: So what is the hierarchy of the `licenseID` values? What if `019` and `120` and `085` exists for the same person? Which one would you want to show?

Comment: The only ones that make a difference to this customer are 1 and 5.  All others are a different kind of license and should be included in the results.

Answer (score 0):

`row_number()` the output ordering by `licenseID desc`, so 5 is before 1, take rn=1.

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over( 
          partition by case when [license ID] = 1 or [License ID] = 5 then 1 else [License ID] end, firstname, lastname, -- .. key columns here            
          order by [License ID] desc) rn
      from (
       -- your query here
       -- excluding ORDER BY
      ) t
) t
where rn=1
order by firstName, Lastname -- , ...
```

Demo

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over( 
          partition by case when [license ID] = 1 or [License ID] = 5 then 1 else [License ID] end, firstname, lastname        
          order by [License ID] desc) rn
      from ( 
       values 
        ( 'a', 'b', 1)
       ,( 'a', 'b', 5)
       ,( 'a', 'b', 7)
       ,( 'a', 'b', 10)
       ,( 'b', 'b', 1)
       ,( 'b', 'b', 5)
       ,( 'b', 'b', 8)
       ,( 'b', 'b', 9)
       ,( 'c', 'd', 1)
       ,( 'c', 'd', 11)
       ,( 'c', 'd', 12)
      ) t(firstname, lastname, [License ID])
) t
where rn=1
order by firstName, Lastname
```

Returns

```
firstname   lastname    License ID  rn
a   b   5   1
a   b   7   1
a   b   10  1
b   b   5   1
b   b   8   1
b   b   9   1
c   d   1   1
c   d   11  1
c   d   12  1
```

eliminates `License ID`=1 when 5 is present in the group.

Comment: This didn't work.  I see what you were going for, but it only returns one less record.  I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.  I will keep trying, though.  Thanks for the start!

Comment: @Carthax , see demo in the updated answer. Please provide sample data and desired result to clarify what is not working.

Comment: see my update to the original question.  The customer clarified his needs, resulting in an entirely different query.